# Vue: Selecting an option while setInterval is firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having trouble selecting an option while a setInterval on the page is firing. The crux of the issue is that **an option cannot be selected if it is selected at the same time as the setInterval timer fires**.

```js
let updateDelay = 100;

var vueObj = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
    timer: 60,
    choice: ''
  }
})

setInterval(function() {
  vueObj.timer = vueObj.timer - updateDelay/1000;
}, updateDelay);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id='timer'>Timer: {{ timer.toFixed(1) }}</div>
  <br>
  <select v-model='choice' size=3>
    <option v-for='item in items' :value='item'>{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

1. keyboard selecting works fine.
2. works fine when `v-model` is removed from the `select`.
3. works better when timer fires less often.

http://jsfiddle.net/1bv7se9h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it seems that there is a problem with Vue. You should open an issue on the vueJS repo: https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue

However, you are able to run your code by coding the v-model yourself:

```
<select size="3" @input="choice = $event.target.value">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bv7se9h/36/

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I've opened an issue as you suggested.